# AES Encryption in Nodejs does not work as it works in PHP

Tags: node.js, aes

**NODE.JS CODE (DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED)**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var input = '200904281000001|DOM|IND|INR|10|orderno_unique1|others|http://localhost/sample/Success.php|http://localhost/sample/failure.php|TOML';

var Key = "qcAHa6tt8s0l5NN7UWPVAQ==";
Key =  new Buffer(Key || '', 'base64');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', Key);

var actual = cipher.update(input, "utf8", "base64");
actual += cipher.final("base64");
console.log(actual);
```

**Actual Output**

> bIK4D0hv2jcKP3eikoaM7ddqRee+RrT2FDOZA+c2sldyrqP+NrmgYOEXklUrSBQiU7w7e90nzFl/mpidy/Q8FD692bFLnESiNqGEQ7er44BXxFtNo6AKvpuohz31zm9JupJXL3jhOC+47mvDHokR4b9euDzPFitTJQW55JuSyvJphOKdiXjH+lGKxXKWsODq

**Expected Output**

> ncJ+HX6zIdrUfEedi7YC82QOUARkySblivzysFbMqaYEMPj7UfMlE4SEkDcjg+D9dE5StGJgebSOkL7UuR6fXwodcgL0CSRds0Y+hX27gKUZK45b7Tc0EjXhepwHJ/olSdWUCkwRcZcv+wxtYzOH7+KKijJabJkU1/SF1ugExzcnqfV2wOZ9q79a4y/g3cb5

**PHP CODE (WORKS AS EXPECTED)**

```
include('CryptAES.php');

//Testing key
$Key = "qcAHa6tt8s0l5NN7UWPVAQ==";

//requestparam Testing - TOML 
$input  ="200904281000001|DOM|IND|INR|10|unique_10005|others|http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentSuccess.php|http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentFailure.php|TOML";

$aes = new CryptAES();
$aes->set_key(base64_decode($key));
$aes->require_pkcs5();

echo $aes->encrypt($input);
```

Comment: How to get CryptAES.php ?

Comment: Note that you are using AES wrong, you **must** use an initialization vector.

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue with using PHP's inbuilt mcrypt library. It pads the key in a different manner as node.js. This issue was bugging me a lot a few months ago, and there is a [workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786025/mcrypt-js-encryption-value-is-different-than-that-produced-by-php-mcrypt-mcryp). What I did was use a small php command line script with my node.js app to handle encryption and decryption.

Comment: We are integrating with a Payment Gateway and the encoded string is provided by that. They are using the same code with multiple clients (JAVA, PHP etc.) so it's definitely not a PHP only issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your two input strings are different. On Node.js, you are using

```
200904281000001|DOM|IND|INR|10|orderno_unique1|others|
http://localhost/sample/Success.php|
http://localhost/sample/failure.php|TOML
```

whereas on PHP it's:

```
200904281000001|DOM|IND|INR|10|unique_10005|others|
http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentSuccess.php|
http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentFailure.php|TOML
```

They differ in the domain as well as the second-last string in the first line. Then, you do not explain where your `CryptAES` function in PHP comes from. As you do not specify any parameters, one can only guess that it's AES with 128 bits. What are its defaults? What kind of padding is used? CBC mode or EBC mode? …?

Questions over questions one can not answer for now.

For testing, I wrote a small Node.js script that takes both of your input strings, and tries *all*  ciphers available in Node.js (you can get them using [crypto.getCiphers()](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_getciphers)) combined with all possible encodings Node.js supports (i.e., `utf8`, `ascii`, `utf16le` and `ucs2`). None of them resulted in the string you gave as expected.

So, although this is not a real answer, I hope that this helps you anyway, at least a little step into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Golo. We had also tried all the ciphers in a loop before giving up. No cipher gave the result that we were expecting.