# Returning 2 Values from a series of functions

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

Hi and good day to all members, admin and to everyone. I would like to ask a question that has a connection from my previous post which can be seen here entitled [Crypto-Js different output from mcrypt Upon chage of data to encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393820/crypto-js-different-output-from-mcrypt-upon-chage-of-data-to-encrypt/24394396?noredirect=1#comment37732441_24394396). Now my question is I made another php function that will eventually call this function stated in the link. See below the basic php function I created.

```
function login($word,$word2)
{

$word = mcrypts_encrypt($word);
$word2 = mcrypts_encrypt($word2);

    return $word;
    return $word2;

}
```

Now my question is this, I have tried placing the $word and the $word 2 with real data such as CROW and Blader but It only echoes the encrypted word of CROW **($word)** and not Blader **($w0rd2)**.

For reference purpose I will also include the script for the encrypt.

**MCRYPT_ENCRYPT**

```
function mcrypts_encrypt($encrypted)
{
//Padding 6/25/2014
    $pad = 16 - (strlen($encrypted) % 16);
    $encrypted = $encrypted . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
//Encrypt//Decode
    $iv = base64_decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');
    $key = base64_decode('ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==');
    $plaintext = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,  $iv );
//Return encrypted Data
    return base64_encode($plaintext);
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you be more clear Sir.

Comment: `return {$word, $word2};` Also, in javascript, your variables don't need to start with the dollar sign.

Comment: I'm sorry sir but this is not a javascript. As you can see on my second code this is a function created using php only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `return` from a function once, at that point, the flow of code is returned back to the caller.

To pass multiple values back to the caller, return an array containing both of the values, e.g.

```
function login($word,$word2)
{
    $word = mcrypts_encrypt($word);
    $word2 = mcrypts_encrypt($word2);

    return array($word, $word2);
}
```

and use as this;

```
$encrypted = login('first-word', 'second-word');
echo $encrypted[0]; // the first word, encrypted
echo $encrypted[1]; // the second word, encrypted
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Sir. I used it as a reference to what I'm doing right now and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<?php
function login($word,$word2)
{
    $word = mcrypts_encrypt($word);
    $word2 = mcrypts_encrypt($word2);
    return array($word, $word2);
}
function mcrypts_encrypt($encrypted)
{
   //Padding 6/25/2014
    $pad = 16 - (strlen($encrypted) % 16);
    $encrypted = $encrypted . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    //Encrypt//Decode
    $iv = base64_decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');
    $key = base64_decode('ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==');
    $plaintext = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,  $iv );
    //Return encrypted Data
    return base64_encode($plaintext);
}

var_dump(login("test1", "test2"));
?>
```

outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "eeyZfxyUnMykJ23fMamEBQ=="
  [1]=>
  string(24) "0egb4dfuXbgFg7GzuuBZcQ=="
}
```

Comment: But when I tried to comment this an error shows.`Array to string conversion`

Answer (score 0):

```
function login($word,$word2)
{

    $word = mcrypts_encrypt($word);
    $word2 = mcrypts_encrypt($word2);
    $returnArray["user"]  = $word;
    $returnArray["pass"]  = $word2;
    return $returnArray;   
}
```

function call

```
$loginValues  = login('CROW','Blader');
extract($loginValues);
print $user; // prints $word
print $pass; // prints $word2
```